# Scrolling within a ScrollView

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

For previous versions of Windows Phone, if you had a scrollable control within a `ScrollView`, then you could set `UseOptimizedManipulationRouting` to `false` so that the inner control got a chance to handle the manipulation events first. This does not seem to exist on Windows Phone for WinRT. Does anyone know what the correct solution would be in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, you need to set `ManipulationMode` to something like [`ManipulationMode="System,TranslateX"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationmodes.aspx) (i.e. include the `System` flag with your other modes that you want enabled), then call [`CancelDirectManipulations()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx) when you want to prevent the system from continuing the processing of direct manipulations on the `ScrollViewer`.

[Here's a sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-input-and-manipulation-44125241/sourcecode?fileId=86578&pathId=962809525) that uses the `CancelDirectManipulations()` method.